# A system function to convert relative path to full path that works even for non-exsting paths?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, path, relative-path

This question has been asked before, but pretty much all the answers boil down to the `realpath` function. Which doesn't work for paths that do not exist. I need a solution that will, and I want to call a POSIX or OS X framework function rather than hand-parse strings.

To reiterate: I need a function that takes an arbitrary path string and returns the equivalent path with no "./" or ".." elements.

Is there such a solution?

Comment: You should specify in more details what you really want to do, and give *several* examples (including some where directories referred in the path does not exist)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I have quite clearly explained what I want to do, in my opinion. What needs clarification?

Comment: How do you handle `/tmp/someinexistentdirectory/foobar` and `/tmp/someinexistentdirectory/../foobar` ? I downvoted your question since you did not tell how.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't see anything that needs to be done with that path, it's fine as it is.

Comment: Then my answer should be enough. And you should explain **why** you want to do so. There are very good reasons to keep `../somedir/path` (where `../somedir` exists) as it is!

Comment: It is fair to expect this bit of functionality to be present in standart libraries, the question does not earn a downvote. A path is a notation scheme, and has nothig to do with inodes, or whatever constraints an implementation can impose _when a path is fed into it_. Be honest and say it's a particular POSIX limitation, rather than kicking dust up around the case and confusing people and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there can be such a solution? I believe that not (because some directories could be typos or symbolic links to be created).

What do you expect your `betterrealpath` function to return for `/tmp/someinexistentdirectory/foobar` ?  Perhaps the user intent was a symbolic link from his `$HOME` to `/tmp/someinexistentdirectory` ? Or perhaps it is a typo and the user wants `/tmp/someexistentdirectory/foobar` ...? And what about `/tmp/someinexistentdirectory/../foobar`? Should it be canonicalized as `/tmp/foobar`? Why?

Maybe using first [dirname(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dirname.3.html), then doing [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) on that, then appending the [basename(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) of the argument should be enough? In C something like:

```
  const char*origpath = something();
  char*duppath = strdup(origpath);
  if (!duppath) { perror("strdup"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  char*basepath = basename(duppath);
  char*dirpath = dirname(duppath);
  char*realdirpath = realpath(dirpath, NULL);
  if (!realdirpath) { perror("realpath"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  char* canonpath = NULL;
  if (asprintf(&canonpath, "%s/%s", realdirpath, basepath) <= 0) 
    { perror("asprintf"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  free (duppath), duppath = NULL;
  basepath = NULL, dirpath = NULL;
  /// use canonpath below, don't forget to free it
```

<sup>Of course that example won't work for `/tmp/someinexistentdirectory/foobar` but would work for `/home/violet/missingfile`, assuming your home directory is `/home/violet/` and is accessible (readable & executable) ...</sup>

Feel free to improve or adapt to C++ the above code. Don't forget to handle failures.

Remember that [i-nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) are central to POSIX filesystems. A file (including a directory) can have one, zero, or several file paths... A directory (or a file) name can be `rename`-d by some other running process...

Perhaps you want to use a framework like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/); they might provide something good enough for you...

Actually, I suggest you to code your `betterrealpath` function entirely yourself, using *only* [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) on Linux. You'll then have to think about all the weird cases... Also, use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on [realpath(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) to understand what it is doing...

Alternatively, don't care about non-canonical paths containing `../` or symbol links in directories, and simply prepend the current directory (see [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html)) to any path not starting with `/` .......

Comment: There must be a solution. There is one on Windows, for example. If the system doesn't know any better (e. g. the path does not exist), it should at least expand "." and ".." properly.

Comment: This is a *very wrong* reasoning. Windows file systems have a semantics which is not POSIX at all. POSIX have hard links, perhaps even on directories...

Comment: Windows has links, too. Besides, I don't expect the system to guess anything. I just need it to clean up existing paths, and convert non-existing ones to the absolute form.

Comment: Qt can solve this problem easily, but I'm writing a cross-platform library with no external dependencies.

Comment: There doesn't *have* to be a solution.  Maybe your problem is sufficiently limited that it has a solution, but that it is not true in general.

Comment: I have done that before and quickly learned that it's the last resort solution. Qt source code is mostly terrible and not meant to be read by humans.

Comment: It seems that your answer assumes that the directory part of the path exists, and only the file does not. That's often not the case when I need this function.

Comment: You don't want to write the function yourself, you don't want to use an external library function, and Posix doesn't provide a suitable function - you will have to relax a requirement.

Comment: Hence, there is no general solution, as I wrote at first in my answer

Comment: @MartinBonner: I expect there to be such a function in the OS X objective-C frameworks, which is the native API for that OS.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: you won't have any *general* solution for a POSIX filesystem on MacOSX, or an NFS one.